# Observable fork join does not work

Tags: angular, rxjs

H, I am having issues in properly using rxJs observable.  My requirement is to get all chat rooms on a Book (if room is not available create one new chat room)
I am using below code and the observable in chat component never getting called.

my Chat component

```
@Component({
selector: 'chat',
templateUrl: './chat.component.html'
})
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {
this.selectbookStream.subscribe(bookId=>
{ 
 this.chatService.getRooms(book id)
    .subscribe(rooms => {
      console.log("in chat component");
      console.log(rooms);
      this.rooms = rooms;
    });
})
}
```

My chat Service

```
@Injectable()
 export class ChatService {
    public getRooms(bookID) {
      console.log("in get rooms")
      return this.thisPartyChatService.createRooms(bookID).map(r=>r)

   }
 }
```

ThirdParty chat service

```
 public createRooms(bookID: string): Observable<any> {
let rooms = [];

this.modelService.getBookDetails(bookID).subscribe(book=> {

  this.getRoom(book.name).subscribe(r => {
    if (Object.keys(r).length === 0) {
     rooms.push( this.createRoom(book.name).map(res=>res))
    } else {
     // rooms.push(Observ)
      rooms.push(Observable.of({
        'id': r.id,
        'type': r.type,
        'title': r.title,
        'name': r.title,
        'created': r.created
      })
      )
    }

  })

});
return Observable.forkjoin(rooms);

}


 public createRoom(bookID: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl.room, { 'title': bookID, 'teamId': 
        teamId }, this.generateHeader()).map(res => res.json);
  }

  public getRoom(modelId: string): Observable<any> {
    this.roomTitle = modelId;
    // search all rooms in CISCO sparck and match with modelId
     return this.http.get(this.apiUrl.room, this.generateHeader())
         .map(this.findRoom);
  }


  private findRoom(res: Response) {
   let body = res.json();
  let room: any;
  body.items.forEach(element => {
  if (element.title == this.roomTitle)
    return element;
  });
  return {};
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using `forkJoin` though. It sounds like you want `defaultIfEmpty`. `forkJoin` is for running multiple observables in parallel (theoretically anyway) and combining their results predictably.

Comment: I am very new rxJS, can you give little more details on how to use defaultEmtpy in my case ..?

Comment: It yields elements from the source or, if the source is empty, it yields the specified default value. Ex: `Observable.from([]).defaultIfEmpty(1)` will yield `1`.

Comment: thank you for your input, I will try to change my code

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the structure of `createRooms()` method. Basically you have the following:

```
public createRooms(bookID: string): Observable<any> {
    let rooms = [];

    this.modelService.getBookDetails(bookID).subscribe(book => {
        this.getRoom(book.name).subscribe(...);
    })

    return Observable.forkjoin(rooms);
}
```

Nesting `subscribe()` calls is always a warning sign.

I guess `getBookDetails` or `getRoom` are asynchronous functions so when the code reaches `return Observable.forkjoin(rooms)` the `rooms` array is always empty.

So I'd recommend you to restructure your code. For example like this (I didn't test it but you should get the point).

```
public createRooms(bookID: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.modelService.getBookDetails(bookID)
        .concatAll()
        .concatMap(book => this.getRoom(book.name))
        .concatMap(room => {
            if (Object.keys(r).length === 0) {
                return Observable...
            } else ....

        });
}
```

Comment: my  .modelService.getBookDetails gives array of books , I need to check and create rooms for all elements in the array.  I tried using concatMap and did not gave expected results

Comment: You can use `.concatAll()` to unpack the array into separate emissions.

Comment: concatAll is not working for me .. may be i am using it wrongly , its throwing compilation errors

Comment: I have no idea what's the structure of your data, so I can help you.

Comment: ok let me give little more details -   getBookDetails  returns a json object `{'name':'book-1',projects:[{'name':'P1'},{'name':'P2'},{'name':'P3'}]}` after getting these details , for book name and all pojrects, I need to check whether a room exists or not, if not I need to create one room.  (checking and creating a room used two separate http calls)

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the service isn't being called since you need to call it inside of a function. For example, your component `implements OnInit` so you could put your service call inside that function and have the component  end up like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'chat',
    templateUrl: './chat.component.html'
})
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {

    public rooms = [];

    public ngOnInit() {

        this.selectbookStream.subscribe(bookId => { 
             this.chatService.getRooms(book id)
                .subscribe(rooms => {
                  console.log("in chat component");
                  console.log(rooms);
                  this.rooms = rooms;
                });
        })  
    }
}
```